# Is there a way to see the average reputation of users answering specific tags?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if it is possible to see the average reputation of users whom answer specific types of questions.

For example, I want to know what is average of reputation for people who answer C++ questions.

Is this possible?

Comment: [SE Data Explorer](data.stackexchange.com) is your friend.  Only updated weekly, but should be good for your purposes.  Someone may already have a sikmilar query you can search for, but if not, then  you can write your own.

Comment: Why do you find this necessary?  Just curious.

Comment: If one answerer in a tag is Jon Skeet and the rest have 1 rep, is that better or worse than all answerers having 10K? Both those situations might result in the tags having roughly the same average.

Comment: If I answer 10 questions and someone else answers only 1 does that mean I contribute 10 times as much to the average rep score as the other person or not?

Comment: @Makoto I wanted to calculate a parameter that shows 'how active is this user in comparison to all others answering these types of questions on site?'. maybe rep is not a good factor, so right now, I'm rethinking calculation of parameter. I think this can show how enthusiastic someone is in solving problems.

Comment: @RobertLongson above comment.

Comment: it's probably pretty low, considering the avg rep overall is pretty low